# Need some advice in DoTween methods

Tags: unity-game-engine, dotween

I have some problems on device with tween

```
private void PaintWay(List<Vector3> way, int CurrentFaceIndex)
    {
        var end = way.Last();
        var start = way.First();

        Material ToPaint = new Material(ObjPresenter.Way.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial);

        coloredWays = new List<GameObject>();

        DOTween.To(() => start, x => start = x, end, AnimationMovePlayerDuration)
            .SetEase(AnimationMovePlayerEase)
            .SetOptions(true)
            .OnStart(() =>
            {
                if (ObjPresenter.Faces[CurrentFaceIndex].PlacesToInstantiate[(int)start.x, (int)start.y].transform.childCount == 0)
                {
                    var pathway = Instantiate(ObjPresenter.Way, ObjPresenter.Faces[CurrentFaceIndex].PlacesToInstantiate[(int)start.x, (int)start.y]);
                    pathway.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = ToPaint;
                    coloredWays.Add(pathway);
                }
            })
            .OnUpdate(() =>
            {
                if (ObjPresenter.Faces[CurrentFaceIndex].PlacesToInstantiate[(int)start.x, (int)start.y].transform.childCount == 0)
                {
                    var pathway = Instantiate(ObjPresenter.Way, ObjPresenter.Faces[CurrentFaceIndex].PlacesToInstantiate[(int)start.x, (int)start.y]);
                    pathway.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = ToPaint;
                    coloredWays.Add(pathway);
                }
            });
    }
```

So problem appears when i got long path. My path has free space without color parts. I use setOptions to snap movement from vector2(floats) to vector2(ints)

i except path without uncolored blocks

Comment: Found something -> because i use non-linear ease mine round to int things can leave some integers. Hmm, any suggestions?